# disassemble ELF file (Linux/ubuntu)

Tags: linux, unix, assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I want disassemble ELF file and then add my assemblies then reassemble it

- I used :
- **objdump -D hello.elf > hello.asm ----> fasm hello.asm hello.elf -m 1000000**
- I have an error:

  **flat assembler  version 1.73.22  (1000000 kilobytes memory)
  hello.asm [87582]:
  2ab2c:   e9 3f 9c 70 7e          jmp    7e734770 <stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x7e3274c0>
  processed: 2ab2c:e9 3f 9c 70 7e jmp 7e734770<stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x7e3274c0>
  error: value out of range.**

Comment: `objdump` does not produce output that can be assembled again.  Consider using the `objconv` utility from Agner Fog's website, which can generate FASM compatible output.  Be aware that the output may be a lot larger than you expect though.

Answer (score 1):

The assembler dialect produced by `objdump` isn't compatible with FASM. Use C compiler or GNU `as` to compile it.

Another problem is that `objdump -D` probably outputs an assembly annotated with extra information, which can't be consumed by the assembler right away.

Comment: `objdump -d` doesn't produce ready-to-assemble output in the first place, even if you strip out the address and machine code columns (which the querent hasn't.)  It doesn't have an option to invent labels on branch targets (or if there is, I didn't see it in the man page).  Agner Fog's `objconv` can disassemble into AT&T, NASM, or MASM syntax that's ready to assemble.  NASM may be close enough to FASM.